Are renormalizability and the criticality of a PDE synonymous?
In the physics literature a quantum field theory is qualitatively classified as  renormalizable, super-renormalizable, or non-renormalizable. This heuristic is based on how many Feynman diagrams converge. In more rigorous approaches to quantum field theory, especially in the stochastic quantization literature, they instead use the classifications critical. sub-critical, and super-critical, as is commonly done in the PDE community.
Since these classifications are used in a seemingly interchangeably way there should be a connection between the two but I haven't been able to see it. Criticality has to do with how conserved quantities or norms behave at various scales and is an analysis done directly on the PDE. In contrast, renormalizability, as described by the divergence of Feynman diagrams and the inclusion of counterterms, is a perturbative description which is done on the Lagrangian and the PDE itself is never considered.
What is the connection between these two points of view?

Potentially related question, as it also relates renormalizability to PDE notions.

The terms describe how the coupling terms of the theory change as one increases the energy. A theory is renormalizable = critical if the coupling terms remain unchanged, super-renormalizable = sub-critical if the coupling terms decrease with increasing energy, and non-renormalizable = super-critical if the coupling terms increase (and eventually diverge in the limit that the energy tends to infinity).
These lecture notes by Witten describe the classification in some detail, with examples, from the perspective of perturbation theory (Feynman diagrams). For a presentation in terms of PDE's (stochastic heat equation), see Stochastic PDEs, regularity structures, and
interacting particle systems by Chandra & Weber.

I'm not sure what is meant to be unchanged/decreasing/increasing here. In a renormalizable theory, the values of the couplings change with energy. The point of renormalizability is that there are only a fixed number of such couplings that need to be adjusted. Non-renormalizability means that the number of such couplings proliferates. Super-renormalizability means that the couplings don't run (just a few infinite constants might have to be subtracted).

I was just referring to the running coupling of a QFT, which scales to 0, $\infty$, or is scale independent; definition 1.3 in the PDE paper I linked to gives a formal description.

Yes, and that is what confuses me - in a renormalizable theory, the coupling runs. So, what is the meaning of "the coupling terms remain unchanged"? The coupling of a renormalizable theory can run to 0 (asymptotic freedom), or to $\infty $ (at least perturbatively, i.e., a Landau pole) ...

A renormalizable theory has a fixed point where the coupling constant is scale invariant, the correspondence to a critical PDE refers to that case, as far as I understand.

Ah, you're talking specifically about the fixed point(s) already, that explains it. Might be worth clarifying that, in case other readers get stuck on this point ...

Thank you for the references! Your answer seems to be in line with the criticality point of view, in which I guess scaling the solution to fine scales is the same as studying the high momentum behavior? Thus we can say that the fine scale behavior tells us how the theory behaves in the UV? Perhaps this is answered in Witten's lecture notes, but what does this point of view have to do with the conventional definition of renormalizability in physics which is based on perturbation theory and Feynman diagrams?

this is discussed in Witten's lecture 2: how a coupling strength $g$ scales under a scaling transformation ($x\mapsto x/t\Rightarrow g\mapsto t^\alpha g$) determines the number of divergent graphs in the Feynman diagram expansion, see theorem 2.1

@CarloBeenakker Thank you!
